# Error: A navigator can only contain 'Screen' components as its direct children

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am new to React Native and I am getting this error, but I am not able to resolve it.

I am following the tutorial from the main [react-navigation page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/), but I am not able to complete it.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen() {
     return (
       <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', 
         justifyContent: 'center'}}>
         <Text> Home Screen </Text>
      </View>
     );
   }

   const Stack = createStackNavigator();
   export default function App() {
     return (
       <NavigationContainer>
         <Stack.Navigator>
           <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
         </Stack.Navigator>
       </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
```

[Screenshoot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnjtJ.png)

Comment: Seems like something wrong with your code formatting, it works well when the code if formatted

Comment: I am facing same issue as yours. your code is okay, all you need is to restart (build) the app from the beginning. it works for me..

Answer (score 11):

I faced similar issue. Turned out that I was using small-case like this : `<Stack.screen>`  instead of `<Stack.Screen>`

Answer (score 8):

Please check your code whenever writing check the tags and spaces and keep your tags in the same line as much as possible if you are using Visual studio use formatters and autocomplete tags which will help you in solving problems.
your code should be as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }} >
            <Text> Home Screen </Text>
        </View>
    );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: For some reason mine only works with this syntax, and your barebones HomeScreen component is great for debugging. I ended up pasting in your code and filling in with my own.

Comment: Could you specify what was wrong originally ?

Answer (score 8):

When creating a new navigator, try rebuilding the application. This solved the problem for me

Reset the metro cache

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Run on android

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Run on iOS

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

Comment: npx react-native run-android 

-- a typo i think.

Answer (score 6):

There is one extra space at the end of some of your components. Putting your code in my IDE and using ESLint for formatting it, this is what I got:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text> Home Screen </Text>{' '} // <--- right here
    </View>
  )
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator()
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />{' '} // <--- right here
      </Stack.Navigator>{' '} // <--- right here
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

You can see some `{' '}` in there. These are extra blank spaces that shouldn't be there. This is what your error is saying, a `' '` was found after the `Stack.Screen`. Removing these empty spaces should solve your problem.

By the way, I would **highly** recommend you to use a JS IDE (if you are not using any) and a linter, like `ESLint`. indentation is a very crucial thing to either avoid this kind of bugs and to let your code more legible.

Comment: This was kind of it for me. I had pasted the Name of a component at the end of my JSX, that I forgot to comment-out or delete after.

Answer (score 5):

Just build again. `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 2):

## import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

> add `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';` at the top (make sure it's at the top and there's
> nothing else before it) of your entry file, such as App.js or App.jsx
> or App.ts or App.tsx. I prefer App insted index

### if not add in index too

#### enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Verify if you added this in your `MainActivity` class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(null);
}
```

Import this on the top of your `MainActivity` class:
`import android.os.Bundle;`

Also, Every time you install a new package in react-native, always rebuild your project.

Kill(Delete) all the running Terminal and then,

Start App:

```
npx react-native start
```

Run Android:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the error was because I used comments in my Stack Navigator, by removing the comments the error was solved.

From:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen name="User" component={User} />    {/* Some Comment */}
</Stack.Navigator>
```

To:

```
<Stack.Navigator>
   <Stack.Screen name="User" component={User} />   
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

No solution? Install the latest **react-native-screens** package. (current version is 3.9.0 in 11.2021)

```
npm i react-native-screens
```

**for ios**

```
cd ios && rm -rf Pods && pod install && cd ..
```

**I recommend a restart with cache clean option**

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using expo you can run to clear the cache which was the reason it didn't work for me

```
expo start -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue, I just had to restart the expo server.